# How to set a symbolic function as non-commutative in NCAlgebra

Tags: ncalgebra

Is there a way you can set a symbolic function to be non-commutative in NCAlgebra? 
For example 
`SetCommutative[f[t]]` returns `CommutativeQ: Tried to set the expression "f[t]" to be commutative"`.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't get it to work exactly: using subscripts is the best I could get i.e. `Subscript[f, t]`. Setting the symbol `f` commutative makes all `Subscript[f, t]` (where `t` is any other symbol) commutative.

Answer (score 0):

In NCAlgebra, functions of a noncommutative symbol are assumed to be noncommutative. So you just have to define `f` to be noncommutative as in

```
SNC[f]
```

(in your example you can skip step because all small caps single letters are set noncommutative by default).

Then if you evaluate

```
g ** f[t]
```

you will get

> NonCommutativeMultiply[g, f[t]]

Also functions of noncommutative variables are assumed to be noncommutative as well and

```
g ** F[t]
```

will also evaluate to

> NonCommutativeMultiply[g, F[t]]

even though `F` is commutative because `t` is noncommutative. However

```
g ** F[T]
```

will evaluate to

> Times[g, F[T]]